# Vuetify v-data-iterator custom "keys: [ ]" names

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to add a custom key names (other than property names) in the Vuetify v-data-iterator component?

[image]

When I changing a values in the array "keys", it is necessary to rename a property names inside the array "items".
I would like to rename the header names (I marked in the screenshot) without renaming the property inside "**items: []**" ("name:", "calories:", "fat:", "carbs:" etc). Headings will contain special characters (like ä, ë, ß etc).
Can someone help me to solve this problem?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-data-iterator
        :items="items"
        :items-per-page.sync="itemsPerPage"
        :page.sync="page"
        :search="search"
        :sort-by="sortBy.toLowerCase()"
        :sort-desc="sortDesc"
        hide-default-footer
      >
        <template v-slot:header>
          <v-toolbar
            dark
            color="blue darken-3"
            class="mb-1"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="search"
              clearable
              flat
              solo-inverted
              hide-details
              prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
              label="Search"
            ></v-text-field>
            <template v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp">
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-select
                v-model="sortBy"
                flat
                solo-inverted
                hide-details
                :items="keys"
                prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
                label="Sort by"
              ></v-select>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn-toggle
                v-model="sortDesc"
                mandatory
              >
                <v-btn
                  large
                  depressed
                  color="blue"
                  :value="false"
                >
                  <v-icon>mdi-arrow-up</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  large
                  depressed
                  color="blue"
                  :value="true"
                >
                  <v-icon>mdi-arrow-down</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-btn-toggle>
            </template>
          </v-toolbar>
        </template>
  
        <template v-slot:default="props">
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              v-for="item in props.items"
              :key="item.name"
              cols="12"
              sm="6"
              md="4"
              lg="3"
            >
              <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="subheading font-weight-bold">
                  {{ item.name }}
                </v-card-title>
  
                <v-divider></v-divider>
  
                <v-list dense>
                  <v-list-item
                    v-for="(key, index) in filteredKeys"
                    :key="index"
                  >
                    <v-list-item-content :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
                      {{ key }}:
                    </v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-content
                      class="align-end"
                      :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }"
                    >
                      {{ item[key.toLowerCase()] }}
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </template>
  
        <template v-slot:footer>
          <v-row
            class="mt-2"
            align="center"
            justify="center"
          >
            <span class="grey--text">Items per page</span>
            <v-menu offset-y>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-btn
                  dark
                  text
                  color="primary"
                  class="ml-2"
                  v-bind="attrs"
                  v-on="on"
                >
                  {{ itemsPerPage }}
                  <v-icon>mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <v-list>
                <v-list-item
                  v-for="(number, index) in itemsPerPageArray"
                  :key="index"
                  @click="updateItemsPerPage(number)"
                >
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ number }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>
  
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  
            <span
              class="mr-4
              grey--text"
            >
              Page {{ page }} of {{ numberOfPages }}
            </span>
            <v-btn
              fab
              dark
              color="blue darken-3"
              class="mr-1"
              @click="formerPage"
            >
              <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
              fab
              dark
              color="blue darken-3"
              class="ml-1"
              @click="nextPage"
            >
              <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-row>
        </template>
      </v-data-iterator>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      itemsPerPageArray: [4, 8, 12],
      search: '',
      filter: {},
      sortDesc: false,
      page: 1,
      itemsPerPage: 4,
      sortBy: 'name',
      keys: [
        // Custom names here
        'Name',
        'Calories',
        'Fat',
        'Carbs',
        'Protein',
        'Sodium',
        'Calcium',
        'Iron',
      ],
      items: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          sodium: 87,
          calcium: '14%',
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 129,
          calcium: '8%',
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          sodium: 337,
          calcium: '6%',
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 413,
          calcium: '3%',
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          sodium: 327,
          calcium: '7%',
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          sodium: 50,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          sodium: 38,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          sodium: 562,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          sodium: 326,
          calcium: '2%',
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          sodium: 54,
          calcium: '12%',
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    numberOfPages () {
      return Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.itemsPerPage)
    },
    filteredKeys () {
      return this.keys.filter(key => key !== 'Name')
    },
  },
  methods: {
    nextPage () {
      if (this.page + 1 <= this.numberOfPages) this.page += 1
    },
    formerPage () {
      if (this.page - 1 >= 1) this.page -= 1
    },
    updateItemsPerPage (number) {
      this.itemsPerPage = number
    },
  },
})
```

**This method doesn't work for me (data is not displayed):**

```
keys: [
  'Custom name for Name',
  'Custom name for Calories',
  'Custom name for Fat',
  'Custom name for Carbs',
  'Custom name for Protein',
  'Custom name for Sodium',
  'Custom name for Calcium',
  'Custom name for Iron',
],
items: [
  {
    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
    calories: 159,
    fat: 6.0,
    carbs: 24,
    protein: 4.0,
    sodium: 87,
    calcium: '14%',
    iron: '1%',
  },
 ...
```

**Demo code:**
https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/GRNrddz

Answer (score 0):

You create a dictionary mapping keys to custom names:

```
let customNames = {
  key1: "Custom name 1",
  key2: "custom name 2",
  //...
}
```

Then you reference those value in default slot template:

```
// ...
<v-list-item
  v-for="(key, index) in filteredKeys"
  :key="index"
>
  <v-list-item-content :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
    {{ customNames[key] || key }}: // Display custom names if set
  </v-list-item-content>
  <v-list-item-content
    class="align-end"
    :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }"
  >
    {{ item[key.toLowerCase()] }}
  </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>
// ...
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to map the keys properly?